# OpenCV Python Stitch unordered images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-stitching

I currently have built a stitching program that is able to stitch any number of images however they have to be of specific order which is a problem for my specific image sets (working with 1452 images). My goal is to create an unordered stitcher program. I am convinced that the issue takes place when I am physically (well virtually) stitching the images to one another.

Here is code for my stitching (assume keypoints found are accurate as well as homography)

```
    def stitchMatches(self,image1,image2,homography):
    #gather x and y axis of images that will be stitched
    height1, width1 = image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1]
    height2, width2 = image2.shape[0], image2.shape[1]
    #create blank image that will be large enough to hold stitched image
    blank_image = np.zeros(((width1 + width2),(height1 + height2),3),np.uint8)
    #stitch image two into the resulting image while using blank_image 
    #to create a large enough frame for images
    result = cv2.warpPerspective((image1),homography,blank_image.shape[0:2])
    #numpy notation for slicing a matrix together allows you to see the image
    result[0:image2.shape[0], 0:image2.shape[1]] = image2
    return result
```

I believe the issue is with these two lines.

```
result = cv2.warpPerspective((image1),homography,blank_image.shape[0:2])
result[0:image2.shape[0], 0:image2.shape[1]] = image2
```

When I run the code on an ordered image (image 1 is north east most)set this is the result.

[image: Ordered Images]

However when I run the images in the reverse order I get this result.

[image]

To my understanding, this is because I have set the resulting image shape to map to image 2 but haven't been able to develop a work around.

Here is a photo of multiple images showing the same issue of the images getting cropped out.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.